# Create a Stored Procedure Debug

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Using the data and schema from this site: Using the data from this site: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-sample-database/

I am given the prompt:

> Create a stored procedure called placeOrder() that can be called to insert a new order in the database. It will receive a customerId as an INT, a productId as an INT and a qty as an INT and return (as anoutput parameter) the order_id of the new row created in table orders.
>
> This stored procedure will find the store with the largest stock of that particular product and assign that store to the order. The order_status should be set to 1 (i.e. Pending), the current system date (see function CURDATE) will be assigned to order_date, column required_date will be 7 days from the current system date (see function ADDDATE) and the column staff_id will be assigned for anyone that works in the selected store (per previous requirement). Since the order_id column is not an auto-incremented column you need to calculate the value for it. You can use max(order_id) to find out the highest order_id in the table.
>
> The order_item row shall be set to the productId and qty passed to the stored procedure. The item_id shall be set to 1 (since this order will only have one item).The list price should be retrieved from the products table using the passed productId. The discount value should be set to 0

If I'm understanding the prompt correctly, I need to first the store id which has the most of a particular product. Once I have that store, I need to insert a new row of data into the table "orders" with the essential data being order_id, customer_id, order_status, order_date, required, date, and staff_id.   **I do NOT understand what the last part of the question is asking/how to go about solving.**

Here's my current code, but I'm almost positive it's chalk full of errors and notes and missing pieces so please help me out where you can:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE procedure placeOrder (IN customerID INT, IN productID INT, IN QTY INT, OUT order_id INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE customerID INT;
DECLARE produtcID INT;
DECLARE quantity INT;

SELECT customer_id INTO customerID from customers where customer_id = customerID;
SELECT product_id INTO productID from  order_items where product_id = productID;
SELECT quantity INTO qty from order_items where quantity = qty; 

/**find store id with max stocks of product**/
select st.store_name, sk.store_id from stocks as sk
INNER JOIN
stores as st
ON sk.store_id = st.store_id
WHERE max(sk.quantity)
GROUP by sk.product_id;

select st.store_id from stores as st
INNER JOIN orders as o
ON st.store_id= o.store_id

Insert into orders (order_id, customer_id, order_status, order_date, required_date, staff_id)
WHERE order_status = '1',
AND order_date = select(curdate()),
AND required_date = adddate('order_date' +7),
AND staff_id = /**ANYONE from store listed in precious query (how do I relate these two queries)**



END
```

Comment: You don't use `DECLARE` to declare procedure parameters. They're already declared in the parameter list.

Comment: There's no need for statements like `SELECT customer_id INTO customerID from customers where customer_id = customerID;` You already have the `customerID` in the variable, this just sets it to the same value.

Comment: `WHERE max(sk.quantity)` is not how you find the store with the maximum quantity. Use `SELECT TOP 1 ... ORDER BY sk.quantity DESC`

Comment: 3 days ago you struggled with a similar procedure (same tutorial) using MySQL. Now, mysteriously, you are using SQL Server? Are you sure you know which one you are using? The syntax and functionality differ.

Comment: @Barmar , Thanks so much for the feedback. I'm doing my best to follow along the lectures and notes and sometimes the prof has the "declares" and sometimes he doesn't so I thought better safe than sorry.
-I've removed the `DECLARE` lines
-Are you recommending that I remove the first 3 select lines entirely? Do I not need to have the `INTO` clause somewhere?

Comment: @SMor, I'm definitely using MySQL (on Workbench) and am still trying to figure out functions vs procedures. I'm not sure where I implied I was using Server, but I apologize as I'm really out of my depth here. Edit; ah I see the tag. That was not my intention. I'm not sure if I did that or someone else edited the tag. But I'm def trying for MySQL

Comment: You implied it by using the `sql-server` tag instead of `mysql` tag.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't re-declare function parameters.
2. You don't need to use a `SELECT` query to set variables that are already set in parameters.
3. You're not getting the store with the maximum quantity correctly. Use `ORDER BY sk.quantity DESC LIMIT 1`
4. You need to use `INTO <variable>` in a query to set variables from a query. If you don't do this, the result of the query will be turned into the result of the procedure, which isn't desired here.
5. You don't use `WHERE` in an `INSERT` statement. `WHERE` is used for finding existing rows that match a condition, but `INSERT` is for creating new rows. You use `VALUES()` to list all the values that should be assigned to the specified columns.

```
CREATE procedure placeOrder (IN customerID INT, IN productID INT, IN QTY INT, OUT orderId INT)
BEGIN

DECLARE topStoreId INT;
DECLARE staffId INT;

/**find store id with max stocks of product**/
select sk.store_id 
from stocks as sk
INNER JOIN stores as st
ON sk.store_id = st.store_id
WHERE sk.product_id = productID
ORDER BY sk.quantity DESC
LIMIT 1
INTO topStoreId;

/* Pick an arbitrary staff from the selected store */
SELECT staff_id
FROM staffs
WHERE store_id = topStoreId
LIMIT 1
INTO staffId;

SELECT MAX(order_id)
FROM orders AS o
INTO orderId;

Insert into orders (order_id, customer_id, order_status, order_date, required_date, staff_id, store_id)
VALUES (orderId, customerId, 1, CURDATE(), DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK), staffId, topStoreId);

END
```

Comment: Wow this is great! I've been going down the code to see if I can understand/replicate it and I have a few questions for you so I can better learn, if you don't mind my asking?
1- For the inputs at the start of the procedure, this relates back to my question above- would I ever need to correlate ex: customer_id (from table) INTO customerID (from procedure input line)? When or when can't I do that? I want to make sure that the data is being querried correctly.
2- So you only declared topStoreId and staffID because those were NOT in the procedure in/ouputs, yes?

Comment: 3- 'INTO topStoreId' at the end of the first query- Can I assume that is being used as an alias? So that the entire query result is pulled from that one "topStoreId"?
4- I've never come across the IMAX function. Can you elaborate as to why you put it in there/what it does?
5- DO I have to specify any null values as okay in the Insert section of the code?

Comment: 1. If the input were a product name, you might need to use a query to correlate it to a product ID. Or you might need to use a query to verify that the product ID actually exists.

Comment: 2. Yes, these are local variables being introduced in the procedure, they need to be declared.

Comment: 3. It's just a way to get the result of a query into a variable. You can also use `SET topStoreId = (SELECT ...);`

Comment: 4. It was a typo for `MAX`. 5. Any columns you don't specify in the `INSERT` will get their default values, or `NULL` if they don't have a default. If they don't have a default and they're not nullable, you'll get an error.

Comment: 4- was messing around with the code and figure that it mightve been a typo thanks!

Comment: 5- Re Nulls, when I tried to run the procedure with the prompt follow up "CALL placeOrder( 20, 10, 1, @order_id);" I got an error which said that "'order_id' can't be null", what would you recommend to changing to be "not null"

Comment: There might be some ambiguity because the parameter has the same name as the table column. I've renamed it to `orderId`, see if that fixes it.

Comment: unfortunately yes and no. A new error has popped up saying that 'store_id' doesn't have a default value. I'm not to familair with where defaults go (other than after a declared variable) I put DEFAULT 0 next to topStoreId, but kept getting the same error.
I also tried it after limit 1 in the 'select sk.store' querry, but same error.

Comment: I was missing `store_id` from the `INSERT` query.

Comment: thanks for the catch! I also edited the "values" to be orderID to match the inputs of the procedure. Unfortunately, once I removed all the errors in the process, the entire procedure does not seem to be working as well as I would like. I'm using the test cases provided by the prompt and am getting whole results with nulls across the board. My guess is that the procedure which you created wasn't referencing the order_items table as questioned by the test cases

Comment: Test cases:
CALL placeOrder( 20, 10, 1, @order_id);
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_id = @order_id;
SELECT * FROM order_items WHERE order_id = @order_id;

CALL placeOrder( 11, 12, 2, @order_id);
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_id = @order_id;
SELECT * FROM order_items WHERE order_id = @order_id;

I'll try and rework the procedure to loop in the order_items table as well on in place of a query on my end. If you have any hints, I'd love to hear them and compare my answers